# jQuery fadeIn() specific div when at the top of HTML section

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

The following code is intended to do a number of things:

1) Find the current scroll position

2) For each `.popup_next` (there is one for each section of the site - each section is an `article`) we find it's parent `article` and get it's `offsetTop`.
3) Add 30px to the .offsetTop value and call that our `$offsetHide` because if our scroll current scroll position is greater than offsetTop AND less than `$offsetHide` then we `fadeIn()`, if the scroll position is anywhere outside of that range then we `fadeOut()` the `.popup_next` div.

Sorry that I'm lacking more specific details, but the following code is meant to achieve the effect described above.  I've checked it inside the javascript console and there are no errors.  Unfortunately, syntax seems to have no errors, but nothing is happening with the effect, can anyone spot errors in my code?

See below:

**EDIT: Is there an error in using `$(".popup_next").scroll(function() {` where this function is not looking for a scroll on the whole window but rather only scrolling of the `.popup_next` element? **

**EDIT #2: Here is an example of the effect NOT working: http://jsfiddle.net/XG24G and here is an example of it working correctly when I remove the variables and make them simple static value (granted that `$(this)` is not used so it triggers for all erroneously): http://jsfiddle.net/UdXvM/1 **

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        // gets the position of the window
          var y = $(window).scrollTop();

        $(".popup_next").scroll(function() {
            var $parentOffset = $(this).parent('article').offsetTop();
            var $hideOffset = $parentOffset + 30;
            if( y > ($parentOffset) && y < ($hideOffset) ) {
                $(this).fadeIn('350');}
            if( y > ($hideOffset) ) {
                $(this).fadeOut('500');}
            if( y < ($parentOffset) ) {
                $(this).fadeOut('500');}            
        });
});
```

Comment: Does your `.popup_next` hidden (or `fadeOut`) before fadeIn ? Because if you just fadeIn on a visible element, there'll be no effect.

Comment: It's hidden by CSS with `display: none` by default.  This effect only triggers when the scroll position is between te `$parentOffset` & `$hideOffset` values.

Comment: Mind posting an example of this on jsfiddle? Unless the answer belove did not do it.

Comment: Here is an example of the effect NOT working: http://jsfiddle.net/XG24G/ and here is an example of it working correctly when I remove the variables and make them simple static value (granted that $(this) is not used so it triggers for all erroneously): http://jsfiddle.net/UdXvM/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(".popup_next").scroll` to `$(".popup_next").each`.  As it is, that code is only executed when a `.popup_next` element is scrolled - that is, it's got `overflow: auto;` and scrollbars are visible and it's contents have scrolled.  To have that code execute for each `.popup_next` when the window is scrolled, you want `.each()`.

**Edit:** Also, there is no `.offsetTop()` method.  You want `.offset().top`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/Wcz3R/

**Edit:** Making this correction in your jsfiddle fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/XG24G/1/

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking after my recent edit to the question.  Thanks for pointing that out, but unfortunately I'm still getting null response :(

Comment: Thanks @gilly3!  I see it working in JSfiddle, but when implementing it on my local dev environment, Google Chrome is a throwing an error: `6Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
(anonymous function)script.js:6
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js:2
bscript.js:5
f.event.handlejquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.i.handle.k`